# Plotly Dashboard: How to make a simple dropdown to display figures?

Tags: plotly-dash, dashboard

My figures are saved in a dictionary and they are accessible, but I am lost on what to put on options and value.

```
app = JupyterDash(__name__)
app.layout = html.Div([
    dcc.Dropdown(
        id='launch-data',
        options=[
            {"label":"All","value":"launch_tot_fig"}],
            value=launch_tot_fig
            ),
        

    html.Div(id="dd-output-container")]
    )

@app.callback(Output('dd-output-container', 'children'),Input('launch-data', 'value'))
def update_output(value):
    return 'You have selected "{}"'.format(value)
if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run_server(debug = True)
```

I also have the figure launch_tot_fig that is a pie chart for the launch sites. So that is to show when the input is "All".

[The Dictionary is launchmass with the SPACEX launchsites as keys](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8v9Ps.png)

Answer (score 0):

If you want to show a graph you need to add a graph component to your layout and then use a callback to update it given the dropdown value. You should have something like this :

```
app.layout = html.Div([
    dcc.Dropdown(
        id='launch-data',
        options=[
            {"label": "All", "value": "launch_tot_fig"}, {"label": "Other", "value": "Other"}],
        value="Other"
    ),

    html.Div(id="dd-output-container"),
    
    dcc.Graph(id='my-fig')

]
)
```

And the callback should look like this :

```
@app.callback(Output('my-fig', 'figure'),
              Input('launch-data', 'value'))
def update_output(value):

    fig = px.bar()

    if value == 'launch_tot_fig':
        fig = dictionnary_with_graphs['launch_tot_fig']

    return fig
```